# Positioning two imageViews horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to position two ImageViews horizontally, but I am not able to get it right.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 

        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/some_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"

                android:src="@drawable/some_image_ontop" />



        </RelativeLayout> 

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="fitXY" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/some_other_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/some_other_image_ontop" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I'm trying to stack two images on top of each other in addition to place them horizontally. Someone know what I'm doing wrong to position the two images next to each other?

Comment: Try taking them out of the RelativeLayouts, and adding android:layout_weight=".5" to each ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more simple, enclose your ImageViews inside `LinearLayout` and set its property as `android:orientation="horizontal"`

For example:

```
...
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/some_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                android:src="@drawable/some_image_ontop" />



        </LinearLayout>
...
```

Comment: This soulution would not stack the pictures on top of each other, but it is simpler indeed!

Comment: to stack on top of each other, define your parent layout as **LinearLayout** too and set it as `android:orientation="verticval"`

Answer (score 0):

I were able to figure it out eventually. The RelativeLayouts were set to "match parent" which forced them to take up all the space in the horizontal row, discriminating the other picture.

```
        >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >




            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/espresso_menu_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"

                android:src="@drawable/black_list_2" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="fitXY" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/globe_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/black_list_2" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```